# JupyterLab is broken on my deep learning vm

Tags: google-cloud-platform, debian, virtual-machine, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I cannot open JupyterLab on my deep learning VM.

This is what I get when I collect the Jupyter service logs.

```
Feb 03 22:28:48 melgan-vm bash[998]: [W 2022-02-03 22:28:48.823 NotebookApp] Config option `kernel_spec_manager_class` not recognized by `NotebookApp`.
Feb 03 22:28:48 melgan-vm bash[998]: [W 2022-02-03 22:28:48.828 NotebookApp] Config option `kernel_spec_manager_class` not recognized by `NotebookApp`.
Feb 03 22:28:48 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:48.843 ServerApp] nb_conda | extension was found and enabled by nbclassic. Consider moving t
he extension to Jupyter Server's extension paths.
Feb 03 22:28:48 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:48.843 ServerApp] nb_conda | extension was successfully linked.
Feb 03 22:28:48 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:48.847 ServerApp] jupyter_http_over_ws | extension was found and enabled by nbclassic. Consi
der moving the extension to Jupyter Server's extension paths.
Feb 03 22:28:48 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:48.847 ServerApp] jupyter_http_over_ws | extension was successfully linked.
Feb 03 22:28:48 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:48.861 ServerApp] jupyter_nbextensions_configurator | extension was found and enabled by nbc
lassic. Consider moving the extension to Jupyter Server's extension paths.
Feb 03 22:28:48 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:48.862 ServerApp] jupyter_nbextensions_configurator | extension was successfully linked.
Feb 03 22:28:48 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:48.862 ServerApp] nbclassic | extension was successfully linked.
Feb 03 22:28:48 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:48.862 ServerApp] nbdime | extension was successfully linked.
Feb 03 22:28:51 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:51.116 ServerApp] [nb_conda_kernels] enabled, 2 kernels found
Feb 03 22:28:51 melgan-vm bash[998]: [W 2022-02-03 22:28:51.209 ServerApp] All authentication is disabled.  Anyone who can connect to this server wil
l be able to run code.
Feb 03 22:28:51 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:51.222 ServerApp] nbclassic | extension was successfully loaded.
Feb 03 22:28:51 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:51.224 ServerApp] beatrix_jupyterlab | extension was successfully loaded.
Feb 03 22:28:51 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:51.248 ServerApp] Loading IPython parallel extension
Feb 03 22:28:51 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:51.249 ServerApp] ipyparallel | extension was successfully loaded.
Feb 03 22:28:51 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:51.250 ServerApp] jupyter_http_over_ws | extension was successfully loaded.
Feb 03 22:28:51 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:51.250 ServerApp] [jupyter_nbextensions_configurator] enabled 0.4.1
Feb 03 22:28:51 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:51.250 ServerApp] jupyter_nbextensions_configurator | extension was successfully loaded.
Feb 03 22:28:51 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:51.252 ServerApp] jupyter_server_mathjax | extension was successfully loaded.
Feb 03 22:28:51 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:51.689 ServerApp] jupyter_server_proxy | extension was successfully loaded.
Feb 03 22:28:51 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:51.691 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyt
erlab
Feb 03 22:28:51 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:51.691 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /opt/conda/share/jupyter/lab
Feb 03 22:28:51 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:51.696 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully loaded.
Feb 03 22:28:51 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:51.700 ServerApp] jupyterlab_git | extension was successfully loaded.
Feb 03 22:28:51 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:51.701 ServerApp] [Jupytext Server Extension] Deriving a JupytextContentsManager from LargeF
ileManager
Feb 03 22:28:51 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:51.702 ServerApp] jupytext | extension was successfully loaded.
Feb 03 22:28:51 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:51.703 ServerApp] [nb_conda] enabled
Feb 03 22:28:51 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:51.704 ServerApp] nb_conda | extension was successfully loaded.
Feb 03 22:28:51 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:51.826 ServerApp] nbdime | extension was successfully loaded.
Feb 03 22:28:51 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:51.828 ServerApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/jupyter
Feb 03 22:28:51 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:51.828 ServerApp] Jupyter Server 1.11.2 is running at:
Feb 03 22:28:51 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:51.828 ServerApp] http://localhost:8080/lab
Feb 03 22:28:51 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:51.828 ServerApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8080/lab
Feb 03 22:28:51 melgan-vm bash[998]: [I 2022-02-03 22:28:51.828 ServerApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip
 confirmation).
Feb 03 22:28:51 melgan-vm bash[998]: [W 2022-02-03 22:28:51.833 ServerApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the logs. It says that the browser will not be opened, which might expected if you are running on a server without desktop manager and browser installed (which seems possible given these tags). It looks like you seek generic help on how to setup JupyterLab on GCP; have you followed the official instructions (https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/docs/jupyter) ?

Comment: that is what happened when I followed the official instructions:
`bind [127.0.0.1]:8080: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 8080
Could not request local forwarding.`

I used to open my Jupyterlab directly from Vertex AI>workbench> OPEN JUPYTERLAB but now the OPEN JUPYTERLAB is not showing (load forever).

another way was through this command on SSH `gcloud compute instances describe --project gan-tts-332319 --zone us-west1-b melgan-vm | grep googleusercontent.com` but now it gives no response. 

This can ruin my entire master research!!!